# How to place the placeholder's text right?

Tags: html

A field has a `placeholder` :

```html
<input type="text" name="clt_cin_pass" id="clt_cin_pass" maxlength="25" placeholder="CIN/Passeport" value="foo" />
```

How to place the `placeholder`'s text , here `CIN/Passeport`,  at the field's right ?

Comment: This question is quite similar to [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2610497/448591)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsFiddle for you pheromix,

https://jsfiddle.net/69sp620q/1/

Html

```
<input type="text" name="clt_cin_pass" id="clt_cin_pass" maxlength="25" placeholder="CIN/Passeport" />
```

CSS

```
input[type='text']{
text-align:right;
}
```

Of course you can update this to target a class not just all input tags

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* webkit solution */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { text-align:right; }
/* mozilla solution */
input:-moz-placeholder { text-align:right; }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="clt_cin_pass" id="clt_cin_pass" maxlength="25" placeholder="CIN/Passeport" value="" />
```